# Querying result for the two tables with where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union

I had a code question for one the SQL tests. Needless to say, its some new concept I didn't encounter before.

The tables with {columns} were:

```
 phones {Name, Phone_Number}
 
 calls {id,caller,callee,duration}
```

*Find "names" for those customers whose total **call duration** was *greater or equal than 10 mins*. Note that duration needs to be summed on caller and callee columns to get total duration greater than 10 mins.*

**Condition: show query with only name column.**

What would the approach be?

Am I correct that I need to use join keyword twice and then perform a group by on name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what you need is get caller and callee into the same position in order to sum an individual's duration. After doing that you can join to phones table. That is easiest with UNION of select on call with another select call selecting first caller then callee.  See [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a44068857aab38751072883d43f530e). You did not give complete table definition, missing data types so I had to make some assumptions. None the less the process is the same.

```
with call_list (id, duration) as 
     (select caller id, duration 
        from calls 
       union all 
      select callee, duration 
        from calls
    order by id
     )  
select p.name, p.phone_number, sum(cl.duration) 
  from call_list cl
  join phones    p  on (p.id = cl.id)
 group by p.name, p.phone_number;
```

Comment: It was a on a coding test that I could not copy the test question. Next time I will snippet it. But I needed to get the gist of the method which you did, cheers.